# Select Rows From Second Table Based On id From First

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables

```
1_products
id, code, make, model, fk_group_id

1_stock
id, stock, repair
```

I want to be able to return all of the rows in both tables based on the match in the first. Say `WHERE fk_group_id = 11`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one:

```
SELECT *
FROM products AS p
INNER JOIN stock AS s ON p.id = s.id
WHERE fk_group_id = 11
```